# Equivalent of Unix cat / tail for cmd or PowerShell to flush the current content of a serial port into the stdout without opening it

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, serial-port

There is the `echo` cmd command which can send a string to a COM port without opening it up:

```
echo Hello > COM1
```

I'm aware of the PowerShell (PS) procedure, creating a serial object

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.ReadLine()
$port.Close()
```

But I'm looking for an one-liner equvalent of UNIX's `tail` / `cat` commands to just flush the content into the stdout without opening the port. I have tried different combinations of `copy` and `type` commands. but they do not work. For example

```
type COM7
```

keeps working without reading the data sent to the port. There is also the PS `Get-Content` which seem to be relevant but I don't know how it should be used to read the content of the serial port.

Comment: After creating the object, take a look at `$port|Get-Member`

Comment: @LotPings thanks, but as I mentioned I don't want to define any object. I just want to simply flush the content into the terminal like it is don with cat or tail commands on UNIX.

Comment: Bash and PoweShell have different concepts. In bash everything is a string, so you work with content of devices as string. In PoweShell everything is object, so you have to work with it accordingly.

Comment: @Zalatik but there is echo already! cmd commands are also ok for me.